# No match for 'operator <<'?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a program that uses structures and allows the user to enter a point and then output the point, but when I run the program it is giving me the error: main.cpp:19:10: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}’ and ‘Point’)
     cout << result;

What does it mean?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

// get a point from user input
Point input_point() {
    double x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    Point p = {x, y};
    return p;
}

int main() {
    Point result;
    result = input_point();
    cout << result;
}
```

Comment: You need to implement the operator<< for Point.

Comment: @AnonMail What do you mean I have to implement the operator? Why can't I just use it?

Comment: The standard library provides `operator<<` for standard types, if you want to use it for your own type aka `struct` you have to define `operator<<` for it.

Comment: How would the compiler know how to output a `Point`? It does not. You have to tell it how, by implementing a `operator<<` for the type.

Answer (score 4):

You could overload the operator like this:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Point& p) {
     stream << "[" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "]";
     return stream;
}
```

And your result will be something like this:

```
[1, 2]
```

---

Basically, your overloaded function should take a reference the stream and your object, and then it has to implement the logic to print the object (such as by printing its members) and then it should return the reference to the stream again.

---

Here's the modified program that shows where to insert the function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Point {
    double x, y;
};

 std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream,  const Point& p) {
     stream << "[" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "]";
     return stream;
}
// get a point from user input
Point input_point() {
    double x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    Point p = { x, y };
    return p;
}

int main() {
    Point result;
    result = input_point();
    cout << result;
}
```

Comment: You should not use lvalue reference here for user type, either pas by value or const reference

Comment: @Slava thanks for the suggestion, I fixed it.

Comment: That's weird. According to my textbook, it said the function input_point() shouldn't have to be modified. Is there another way to do that without changing it?

Comment: @YolandaHui I don't see how this answer relates to having to modify `input_point`. It's strictly something you need to add, external to any existing function.

Comment: Doesn't Point input_point() {
    double x, y;
    cin >> x >> y;
    Point p = {x, y};
    return p;
} become std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Point& p) {
     stream << "[" << p.x << ", " << p.y << "]";
     return stream;
}?

Comment: @YolandaHui this wouldn't modify `input_point()`, but instead come somewhere before it. The logic to printing the point structure has to be defined somewhere, perhaps the textbook assumes in this example that this was already done. Just paste this snipped to your code before `input_point()` and it should work.

Comment: @YolandaHui No, you need to *add* an operator overload to describe what you want to happen when you do `std::cout << result;`. It's essentially just an extra function you need to supply.

Comment: @YolandaHui Blaze's answer does *not* modify `input_point`.

Comment: @Blaze I just added that but it won't let me input anything and just jumped straight into some randomly generated results.

Comment: @YolandaHui weird, it works for me on MSVC. I pasted in the full program, does this work?

Comment: Switched to another online compiler, and it works.